# Are Shadowen mutated Feeders?

Tags: shannara

I'm reading *Scions of Shannara*, and something struck me. The way that Cogline and Allanon describe the Shadowen, they sound a lot like the Feeders from the Word & Void series that Nest encounters. I think it was Cogline who had mentioned they were brought into the world by left over magic. Now, Feeders had always been around, but weren't visible to those without magic. Is it possible that this left over magic Cogline mentions mutated the Feeders until they became the Shadowen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no explicit link between the *Shannara* books and the *Word and the Void* until the *Genesis of Shannara* trilogy.  That said, it would not surprise me if Terry Brooks had reused the concept.

The source of the Shadowen is eventually revealed later in the *Heritage* series...

> ... as the Elves.  They had apparently tried to reclaim their older heritage as the primary magic users in the Four Lands, but overuse had led to addiction, and addiction changed them into these wraithlike creatures that could change bodies and feed on magic.  The reason the elves disappeared in the first place is because they couldn't correct the damage and fled rather than face the music.

Given the above, and the later welding of the two series, it could be theorized that the Feeders were a weaker form with the same source... but it would be only a theory.